# JSONPath PHP gives false

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, jsonpath

I've been using [JSONPath](https://github.com/Galbar/JsonPath-PHP) in my Codeigniter 3 Project.
I want to find the result of an expression.

Now, coming to the issue. The Same expression works on an online [json evaluator](https://jsonpath.com/). But the same expression used during the code results into **false**.

Here's the expression

*$.slots[?((('2035-05-16 08:00' >= @.slot_datetime_from && '2035-05-16 08:00' < @.slot_datetime_to) || ('2035-05-16 12:30' > @.slot_datetime_from && '2035-05-16 12:30' <= @.slot_datetime_to)     ) && @.venue_id == '1' && @.court_id == '1')]*

I'm using one JSON. Here's the [link](https://jsonblob.com/814e7799-a9b5-11eb-8560-11f1cabe8a19)

Here's the code which I'm using.

```
$existingEntries = new JsonObject($existingSlotAndCourtEntries);
$result = $existingEntries->{$exp};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer. The author of the library answered it himself.

[Github link](https://github.com/Galbar/JsonPath-PHP/issues/42#issuecomment-830149924)